# Smooth canvas sketching without clearing (redraw)

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, smoothing

I'm trying to find a way to smooth out the points for sketching to get a cleaner result. I've found this example, and the result looks quite good

I've found some ways that use cubic curves to smooth out the edginess, but all of them requires the line to be redrawn from the beginning since they work with multiple points.

My initial idea was to "draw" the final "part" of the line when there are enough points to calculate the bezier (simply 2 frames after points are taken) to overcome the need of "redrawing" every time.

Any ideas/workarounds about this will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your example doesn't appear to be linked; please post some code so we know what you're working with.